# Windows 10 - No Internet connection but connected to the network, and can't shut down or reboot

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, shutdown, reboot

This is a double problem, I installed a new motherboard because my old one broke, and now I'm having non stop problems. I can't turn off or restart my PC properly, it just stays running in a black screen state. I have no idea why it's doing this.

And on top of that every so often my internet will just drop and say I have no connection to the internet, but I'm connected to the network. The network and internet work fine on my Laptop. The wireless adapter is a N300 Belkin. I have tried uninstalling the drivers, which didn't work, and upon reinstalling them I had to restart, which funnily enough, also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A new motherboard has different hardware than your previous motherboard and as such, it has new drivers. Even though installing the drivers may work, its not recommended to just keep using your old windows installation because the problems you describe is exactly what could happen.

To fix this, reinstall windows clean.

Comment: What @LPChip said. You've just changed too much and the system needs a clean reinstallation.